# Using modulus for float values

Tags: php

This might be easy but I'm having trouble figuring out. I'm using the modulus operator to do some calculations and I've come across an issue.

So %2 should give 1 if there's a remainder after division by two and 0 if no left-over. See below, why is the answer "there is a leftover" instead of "no leftovers"? Have I got it the other way around?

```
$a = 5.5;
$b = 0.5;
if ( ( ( $a - $b ) / $b ) %2  == 0 ) { 
    echo "no leftovers";
} else {
    echo "there is a leftover";
}
```

Comment: ... Because `5.5 - 0.5 = 5`, and `5 % 2 = 1`?

Comment: The Modulus operator works with __integers__.... if you try to use it with a float, that float will be cast to integer before evaluating the modulus.... if you need the modulus for float values, then use the [fmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function

Comment: See comment `Operands of modulus are converted to integers (by stripping the decimal part) before processing.` in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker: I've used your answer to answer my own question. So that someone may benefit from it. I've given you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working correctly.  You're subtracting 0.5 from 5.5 to get 5, then dividing this by 2 and checking the remainder, which is 1.  Hence, "there is a leftover".

Edit: it was working as intended but I see you've edited it to divide by 0.5 - why is that?

Comment: Thanks and yes, I've added 0.5 This is my problem. I had it wrong at the time I submit my question.

Comment: That should still work.  I've ran the code and it correctly states "no leftovers"... 5.5 - 0.5 = 5, 5 / 0.5 = 10, 10 % 2 = 0... "no leftovers".

Answer (score 0):

```
( $a - $b ) = 5.0
```

and `5 % 2 = 1`

So result will be always  "there is a leftover"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker).

```
$a = 5.5;
$b = 0.5;
if (fmod( ($a - $b), $b )  == 0 ) { 
    echo "no leftovers";
} else {
    echo "there is a leftover";
}
```

[fmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) is the key when dealing with float.